# Find which tab is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me to identify which tab is active from below code below is my click function

```js
$('.list-group-item').on('click', function (e) {
  var previous = $(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active");
  alert($(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active"));
  previous.removeClass('active'); // previous list-item
  $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated list-item
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="list-group help-group">
            <div class="faq-list list-group nav nav-tabs">
                <a href="#tab1" class="list-group-item active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> General Help (Power
                Apps/Automate)</a>
                <a href="#tab2" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-account"></i>
                Landscape Report</a>
                <a href="#tab3" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-account-settings"></i>
                Mobile</a>
                <a href="#tab4" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-star"></i>
                Maintainability</a>
                <a href="#tab5" class="list-group-item" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="mdi mdi-cart"></i> Errors</a>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i tried putting alert

```
alert($(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active"));
```

it show me

> object object

Comment: You can use it as follow: ```alert($(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active")[0]);```, you get ```[object Object]``` because it is a string representation of a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the attributes of the active element:

```
alert($(this).attr('href'));
```